# C# Windows Application compare input character with string

Tags: c#

I am working on C# windows form. I want to make a comparison as below scenario.

I have two textbox. The first text box (textbox1) is readonly and contain text: "This is my first Windows Application using C#." The second textbox (textbox2) is for user typing the text the same as text in textbox1. If user typed wrong characters I would display the number of characters errors in a label (lblError).

Example: If user type "the" then lblError should display "1"

Thanks,
Man

Comment: And the question is... ?

Comment: Do you want to show error when there is a string mismatch ?

Answer (score 0):

Code example:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void CompareWords(string a, string b)
    {
        List<string> diff;
        IEnumerable<string> set1 = a.Split(' ').Distinct();
        IEnumerable<string> set2 = b.Split(' ').Distinct();

        if (set2.Count() > set1.Count())
        {
            diff = set2.Except(set1).ToList();
        }
        else
        {
            diff = set1.Except(set2).ToList();
        }

        labelWrong.Text = ("Wrong words: " + diff.Count());
    }

    private void CompareChars(string a, string b)
    {
        List<string> diff = new List<string>();
        if (a == b) //Same string, no iteration needed.
            lblWrongChars.Text = ("Wrong chars: " + 0);
        if ((a.Length == 0) || (b.Length == 0)) //One is empty
        {
            lblWrongChars.Text = ("Wrong chars: " + (a.Length == 0 ? b.Length : a.Length));
        }
        double maxLen = a.Length > b.Length ? a.Length : b.Length;
        int minLen = a.Length < b.Length ? a.Length : b.Length;
        int sameCharAtIndex = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < minLen; i++) //Compare char by char
        {
            if (a[i] == b[i])
            {
                diff.Add(b[i].ToString() + ",");
                sameCharAtIndex++;
            }
        }

        lblWrongChars.Text = ("Wrong chars: " + (a.Length - diff.Count()));
    }

    private void txtReadOnly_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        string lastchar_inserted = e.KeyValue.ToString();

        if (lastchar_inserted == "32")
        {
            CompareWords(txtReadOnly.Text, txtUserType.Text);
        }

        CompareChars(txtReadOnly.Text, txtUserType.Text);
    }
}
```